# Spring Mvc integration test failed

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, integration-testing

I have done a Spring Mvc application and I have been trying to write some integration tests, but I keep getting errors. Here is my AgentService:

```
@Service
public class AgentService {

    @Autowired
    private AgentRepository agentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AgencyRepository repoAg;

    @Autowired
    private AgentMapper mapper;

    public List<AgentDto> listByAgency(Long id) {
        List<Agent> agents = agentRepository.findAll().stream().filter(ag -> ag.getAgency().getId().equals(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<AgentDto> mappedAgents = agents.stream().map(agent -> mapper.mapToDto(agent)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return mappedAgents;
    }
}
```

And my AgentController:

```
@Controller
public class AgentController {

    @Autowired
    private AgentService agentService;

    @GetMapping("/viewAgentsPage/{id}")
    public String viewAgentsPage(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listAgents", agentService.listByAgency(id));
        return "agents";
    }
}
```

This is the test I've written:

```
package com.example.awbdproject.controller;

import com.example.awbdproject.models.Agency;
import com.example.awbdproject.models.Agent;
import com.example.awbdproject.services.AgentService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AgentControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    AgentService agentService;

    @MockBean
    Model model;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void showAgentsByAgency() throws Exception {

        List<AgentDto> savedAgents = new ArrayList<AgentDto>();

        Long id = 1L;
        Agency agencyTest = new Agency();
        agencyTest.setId(id);

        AgentDto agentTest = new AgentDto();
        agentTest.setId(1L);
        agentTest.setFirstName("test");
        agentTest.setLastName("test");
        agentTest.setEmail("email@gmail.com");
        agentTest.setAgency(agencyTest);

        savedAgents.add(agentTest);

        when(agentService.listByAgency(id)).thenReturn(savedAgents);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/viewAgentsPage/{id}", "1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("agents"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("listAgents", savedAgents))
                .andExpect(content().contentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"));
    }
```

When I run the test I'm getting this error:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /viewAgentsPage/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost/viewAgentsPage/1]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY", Location:"http://localhost/login"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = http://localhost/login
          Cookies = []
```

What seems to be the issue here? I have never used Mockito and can't seem to wrap my head around it. I think it might have something to do with Spring Security. If it helps, this is my security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
               "/register/**",
               "/js/**",
               "/css/**",
               "/img/**"
       ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
               .permitAll()
               .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
               .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Use `@WebMvcTest(AgentController.class)` instead of `@SpringBootTest`. You are loading everything now which probably isn't what you want. If that is, please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: I am getting the same error. I posted the full stacktrace

Comment: I have updated the error I'm getting now. I think this might be because of Spring Security?

Comment: Looks like unauthenticated request. Try `@WithMockUser` See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-integration-tests

Comment: Thank you! It now works and I've checked your suggested link out and it makes sense! I had some more errors, regarding the returned content type. I have now edited my question and everything works fine.